# Changes "WITH" a diet vs "ON" a diet, which is the best?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Which would be the most correct title for an article that is about what changes in our body when we are on specific kind of diet?

I've got three options: "Pathophysiological changes WHEN ADOPTING a plant-based diet" or "Pathophysiological changes ON a plant-based diet" or "Pathophysiological changes WITH a plant-based diet".

I'm not an english native speaker, but I feel the first best explains the concept, but it's too long, and there's a shorter expression for it. The second gives to me an idea of stillness, like just "being on a diet", with no added meaning. And the third seems the most appropriate to me because it involves the idea of change, of something changing because of something else. Which are your suggestions?

Comment: As a native US English speaker, the first option sounds like the best.  "Too long"?  It's only one word longer!  "Changes with a diet" sounds like the changes are *to* the diet, which is not what we mean.  "On" is acceptable, though.

Comment: Thanks @stangdon for your suggestion. I was also told "changes ON ADOPTING a plant-based diet". Still looking forward to hear more opinions..

Comment: Because you limit the answer to only those three choices, I'll put my thought here, as a comment. For me, there are several other possibilities, e.g., *due to*, *caused by*, *during*, *as an effect of*, *as a result of*, etc. (each suggests a different angle of your article). If you really want to save words, this would work, too: *Plant-based diet: pathophysiological changes*. Too short? You can also use this: *Plant-based diet and its pathophysiological effects*.

Comment: Excellent suggestions @DamkerngT. Please don't limit yourself to a comment. I was actually suggesting 3 possible options but they're not exclusive. If you post an answer I would definitely upvote it and possibly choose as best one, although also the one by user3169 is quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the three choices, *Pathophysiological changes **when adopting/on/with** a plant-based diet*, I agree that *when adopting* is the best one. *With* is a bad choice; and *on*, while may be okay, doesn't sound that good in my opinion.

---

Having said that, I think there are several other choices, and even more choices if we allow a subtle change such as using ***effect(s)*** instead of ***changes*** (they are different words, but if the changes are the main effect(s), *effect(s)* will work equally well, and possibly even better in some variations), or moving the *plant-based diet* to the front.

Here are some possibilities I can think of at the moment:

> *Pathophysiological changes **during** a plant-based diet*
>   (I'd expect that the article will discuss the changes that may happen during such a diet.)
>
> *Pathophysiological changes **from/due to/caused by/as an effect of/as a result of** a plant-based diet*
>   (I'd expect that the article will discuss the effect or the result straightforwardly.)

---

But because this is an article title, you can be deliberately vague, and let the reader relate the diet and the changes together themselves, by using a colon, like this:

> *Plant-based diet: pathophysiological changes*

- Note: I believe you can use either *A plant-based diet* or *Plant-based diet*. The former (*A plant-based diet*) will make it sound like your article is going to discuss a specific plant-based diet, maybe it's a case study, a type of plant-based diet, etc. The latter (*Plant-based diet*) will make it sound more like your article is going to discuss the plant-based diet in general, perhaps with several case studies or several subjects who've tried the diet.

If you think *Plant-based diet: pathophysiological changes* is too short or you want something clearer, you can rephrase it a little, like this:

> *Plant-based diet and its pathophysiological effects*

---

This is by no means exhaustive, and in the end it'll be up to you to choose whatever you think works best for your article. I hope my answer adds some useful information and more possibilities for your article's title. Best of luck!

Comment: There's also: *Pathophysiological changes FROM a plant-based diet*. (One meaning of _from_ is [because of](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/from).)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, J.R. It's included in the answer now.

Comment: Thanks for describing the difference of article usage.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing about *changes** (the state before and after something), I would use *when adopting*

> Pathophysiological changes **when adopting** a plant-based diet.

This fits the meaning of [adopt](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/adopt):

> 3) to choose and follow (a course)

*on* would only include your state when *on* the diet. It does not address conditions before and any *changes*.